# Django - Python getting a list from dictionary return a number and not the list

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form, which one of the fields is a multiselect, I am trying to retrieve all the values that where selected, but form some reason I only get the last item selected:

```
print(type(self.get_form().data))
# <class 'django.http.request.QueryDict'>

print(self.get_form().data)
# <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['K0GeMv5u8pnT3fnS1lnXjgYakuu2mkXg61GKMVuJc2bBnDH1YMTPUHr6iY3rsZ0A'], 'contactID': ['20'], 'locationID': ['2'], 'items': ['1', '3']}>
```

In this point items is equal to: 'items': ['1', '3'], however when i try to get items:

```
    print(self.get_form().data.get('items'))
```

that prints 3

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryDict.get()` returns the last value. It is how it works

If you need it as a normal python dictionary, then convert it using `dict()`:

```
print(dict(self.get_form().data).get('items'))
```

Comment: no, that prints 3 as well i need to get [1,3] if i am selecting item 1 and item 3 or if i am selecting item 1 and 2 i should get [1,2] and not just 2